# ExtensionLoadWarning: Warnings loading extension at .... Electron js And Vue2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron-builder

I am developing a project with vue2-electron builder. But when i run this code, its not displayed.

The error is;

```
(node:10500) ExtensionLoadWarning: Warnings loading extension at C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\project\extensions\nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhblpccpnnnanhbledajbpd:
  Unrecognized manifest key 'browser_action'.
  Unrecognized manifest key 'update_url'.
  Permission 'contextMenus' is unknown or URL pattern is malformed.
  Cannot load extension with file or directory name _metadata. Filenames starting with "_" are reserved for use by the system.    
(Use `electron --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

And my background.js is;

```
'use strict'

import { app, protocol, BrowserWindow } from 'electron'
const path = require('path')
import { createProtocol } from 'vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/lib'
import installExtension, { VUEJS_DEVTOOLS } from 'electron-devtools-installer'
const isDevelopment = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'

protocol.registerSchemesAsPrivileged([
  { scheme: 'app', privileges: { secure: true, standard: true } }
])

async function createWindow() {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    icon: path.join(__dirname, '../build/icons/logo.png'),
    webPreferences: {
      
      nodeIntegration: process.env.ELECTRON_NODE_INTEGRATION,
      contextIsolation: !process.env.ELECTRON_NODE_INTEGRATION
    }
  })

  if (process.env.WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_URL) {
    await win.loadURL(process.env.WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_URL)
    if (!process.env.IS_TEST) win.webContents.openDevTools()
  } else {
    createProtocol('app')
    win.loadURL('app://./index.html')
  }
}

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', () => {
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow()
})

app.on('certificate-error', (event, webContents, url, error, certificate, callback) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  callback(true);
})

app.on('ready', async () => {
  if (isDevelopment && !process.env.IS_TEST) {

    try {
      await installExtension("nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd");
    } catch (e) {
      console.error('Vue Devtools failed to install:', e.toString())
    }
  }
  createWindow()
})

// Exit cleanly on request from parent process in development mode.
if (isDevelopment) {
  if (process.platform === 'win32') {
    process.on('message', (data) => {
      if (data === 'graceful-exit') {
        app.quit()
      }
    })
  } else {
    process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
      app.quit()
    })
  }
}
```

How can i fix.?

I search it from https://github.com/nklayman/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/issues/776
And another link [enter link description here](https://github.com/nklayman/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/issues/923)

Can you help me pls.

Answer (score 0):

That is just a warning related to the `manifest.json` file of the extension and it should not prevent it from working.

By the way, the extension ID `nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd` you are using may not work with Vue2 since it is meant for current maintained versions.

You may consider using the legacy extension ID `iaajmlceplecbljialhhkmedjlpdblhp` of Vue JS.